# Non-prime quaternion in the ring of Hurwitz quaternions - $x$ is a prime iff $N(x)$ is a prime in $\Bbb Z$

Tags: ring-theory, arithmetic, quaternions

We consider $\Bbb H (\Bbb Z)$ the ring of integer quaternions.
We consider $H = \Bbb H (\Bbb Z)\cup \left(\Bbb H (\Bbb Z)+\dfrac{1+i+j+k}{2}\right)$ the eclidean ring called the Hurwitz quaternions.

Let be $x \in \Bbb H(\Bbb Z)$ a non-prime quaternion. Not being a prime in $H$ implies the existence of $a,b \in H$ such as $x = ab$ with $a,b$ non invertible.

Show that you can choose $a$ or $b$ in $\Bbb H (\Bbb Z)$.

*I read this in a paper wich said it was obvious. But cannot figure out why...*

EDIT: apparently, you can even choose $a$ and $b$ in $\Bbb H (\Bbb Z)$.

This result is for the proof that  $x\in \Bbb H (\Bbb Z)$ is a prime iff $N(x)$ is a prime in $\Bbb Z$.

Comment: My guess would be to use $ab=(au)(\overline{u}b)$ for some unit $u$ of the form $u=(\pm1\pm i\pm j\pm k)/2$. I don't remember the details. May be the choice of $u$ depends on $2a$ modulo $4$?

Comment: **What paper?** citation please?